# How do I clean up the .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there git command that can be used to remove lines in .gitignore that are not used?

In other words, I want to remove patterns that will not make a difference for the project.

Comment: Do you mean automatically somehow? Because otherwise: it's just a text file, edit it.

Comment: This is highly dependent on the kind of project that you are working on. Blindly adding/removing patterns from a gitignore should be avoided and all necessary modifications to a gitignore must be a manual process.

Comment: If you're asking for someone to find or write that command, it's out of scope for SO. Have you tried something? What happened?

Comment: Blindly using .gitignore files is the most common way gitignore is used. Copying it from another project or browse github for a gitignore file that is suitable for a certain type of project.

Comment: Question is updated.

Comment: Take a look at SO docs on [`git update-index`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/245/ignoring-files-and-folders/885/ignoring-files-and-directories-with-a-gitignore-file#t=201611191220276268085) and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built in to Git to do this, so you would have to write your own code, probably using [`git check-ignore`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ignore.html).  Such a program would be quite complex since some ignore entries might be unused *because of* other existing ignore entries.  As a somewhat silly example, if one entry says `*.a`, one says `*.b`, and a third says `*.[ab]`, removing either or both of the first two is "safe" (makes no change in what gets ignored) as long as the third remains, but removing the third requires keeping *both* of the first two.  This means that finding a truly minimal set of ignore entries would require trying all combinations.

In any case, it's not a good idea in general.  Suppose, for instance, that the project `.gitignore` contains these two lines (among others):

```
*.dylib
*.dll
```

and that you are working on Linux—but the project, which builds a shared, dynamically loaded library, is not limited to Linux.

These lines are present for, and used by, those working on Macs (the first line) and Windows (the second one).  You will never use them yourself.  Your system builds neither DLLs nor Dylib files; it builds shared library (`*.so`) files instead; and any automatic code you build that tests whether *you* use them will say: no, these are not used.  So you might remove them ... and cause trouble for *other* developers.  If *they* ran your program, it would delete the `*.so` line that *you* are using.

(This happens with IDEs as well, which may create files or directories with "hidden" names that Git can see.  If you use a different IDE from Bob, and Carol uses a third, you may all three need different entries.  It's possible to work around this using your own global "excludes" file, and that's usually the right answer if your editor makes backup files: if Bob's editor makes `*~` while Carol's makes `#*`, Bob can put `*~` in his personal global exclude, and Carol can put `#*` in hers.  Meanwhile if you use `vim`, you would put `.swp` and `*.swp` in yours.  But this also tends to be project-dependent sometimes.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use an IDE, you may try the [.ignore plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495) for IntelliJ IDEA. In my experience, it should do what you seek.

From its features list:

> - Entries inspection (duplicated, covered, unused, relative, incorrect syntax, relative entries) with fix actions

Answer (score 0):

You just open the file and remove the lines that you are not using and save it.

Comment: My whole question was about how to detect which lines those are.

Comment: @AndersLindén well note that *you never actually wrote that*.