# A file does not exist in the file system but .gitignore still lists that file

Tags: git

I had a few files which I added to .git Ignore when they existed but they do not exist anymore. However, they are still listed in .gitignore.

when I do command `git rm --cached` it says that file does not exist for the obvious reasons.

Is there a way that I can tell .gitignore so stop ignoring files that just do not exist anymore?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40692987/6309

Comment: There is no problem with `.gitignore` listing files or patterns that won't match any files right now. If those patterns are never (or not any more) going to match any files, you could just delete them, but they won't cause much of a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the lines from .gitignore and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

.gitignore is just a file which is in your repository.
Edit the file, remove the lines which specify the files you don't want, and commit .gitigore.